# GTM script for detecting adblock not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to detect adblock in GTM with custom HTML tag with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var adClass = 'pub_300x250 pub_300x250m pub_728x90 text-ad textAd text_ad text_ads text-ads text-ad-links';
        var adStyle = 'width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; position: absolute !important; left: -10000px !important; top: -1000px !important;';

        var sendAdBlockEvent = function(result) {
            var data = {
                event: 'adBlock',
                adBlockEnabled: result
            }
            window.dataLayer.push(data);
        }

        var checkElement = function(elem) {
            if (window.document.body.getAttribute('abp') !== null ||
                elem.offsetParent === null ||
                elem.offsetHeight == 0 ||
                elem.offsetLeft == 0 ||
                elem.offsetTop == 0 ||
                elem.offsetWidth == 0 ||
                elem.clientHeight == 0 ||
                elem.clientWidth == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (window.getComputedStyle !== undefined) {
                var elemTemp = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
                if (elemTemp && (elemTemp.getPropertyValue('display') == 'none' || elemTemp.getPropertyValue('visibility') == 'hidden')) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }

        var checkAdBlock = function() {
            //create bait
            var bait = document.createElement('div');
            bait.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
            bait.setAttribute('class', adClass);
            bait.setAttribute('style', adStyle);
            window.document.body.appendChild(bait);

            window.setTimeout(function() {
                sendAdBlockEvent(checkElement(bait));
                window.document.body.removeChild(bait);
            }, 1);
        }

        if (!window.dataLayer) {
            window.dataLayer = [];
        }

        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            checkAdBlock();
        } else if (window.addEventListener !== undefined) {
            window.addEventListener('load', checkAdBlock, false);
        } else {
            window.attachEvent('onload', checkAdBlock);
        }

    })();
</script>
```

It seems to not work properly as only a little above 1% is using adblock (adBlockEnabled equal to 1), and there are more than 25% of sessions without 0 or 1. I have also tried to modify the script and checking adblock instantly (and not on window load event like in the example above) and using trigger on "Window Loaded" or "DOM Ready" with exactly the same results. When I test it on my machine it always work properly.

Any ideas what can be wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to detect adBlock. It is an HTML Custom Tag with a DIV element that will act as AdBlock bait and a JavaScript code (jQuery) that checks if the DIV will be hidden by the AdBlock. A value, 0 or 1, is pushed in the dataLayer so you can adapt it to your needs:

```
<div id="bottomAd" style="font-size: 2px;">&nbsp;</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready( function() {
  window.setTimeout( function() {
    var bottomad = $('#bottomAd');

    if (bottomad.length == 1) {
      if (bottomad.height() == 0) {
        dataLayer.push({'event': 'ir.adBlock', 'adBlockDetected': '1' });
      } else {
        dataLayer.push({'event': 'ir.adBlock', 'adBlockDetected': '0' });
      }
    }      
  }, 1);
});

</script>
```

Source of code: https://www.tagmanageritalia.it/guida-avanzata-tracciare-adblock-google-tag-manager/

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is necessary to edit page content and I need something which si a GTM only solution I may use on every site.

Comment: You don't need to edit page content, just insert the code above in GTM in a Custom HTML tag with a trigger on 'All pages'.